# How can I find out if AdMob has loaded an ad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, error-handling, admob, iad

I'm using `AdMob` as backup for `iAd`, but I'm having trouble finding out if `AdMob` delivers..
With `iAd` I could check with `isBannerLoaded` or something, but not with `AdMob`..
Anyway, I've got everything working now, except when theres no internet connection!
When `iAd` fails to load an ad, and calls `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`, then I initiate the `AdMob`. When testing this, the Error-reason I'm using is "no internet connection", but AdMob doesn't call it's own `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`. It seems like no internet connection isn't an error for AdMob (`GADBannerView*`)

How can I tell if GADBannerView fails?

**EDIT**

Okay, so here's basically code I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initiAdBanner];
    [self initAdMobBanner];
}

-(void)initAdMobBanner{}//initiates variable adMobBannerView(GADBannerView)
-(void)initiAdBanner{}//initiates variable iAdBannerView(ADBannerView)

-(void)hideBanner:(UIView*)banner{} //hides banner if visible
-(void)showBanner:(UIView*)banner{} //shows banner if hidden

//blah blah

-(void)adView:(GADBannerView*)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError*)error
{
    //Never gets called, should be called when both iAd and AdMob fails.
    NSLog(@"AdMobBanner failed.");
    [self hideBanner:banner];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView*)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    //If iAd fails, due to no internet connection or whatever, then it calls this.
    [self adMobRequest];
    [self hideBanner:iAdBannerView];
    [self showBanner:adMobBannerView];
}
```

When iAd fails and calls for `(ADBannerView*)didFailToReceiveAdWithError`, I start the AdMob, but when theres no internet connection, the AdMob won't call the `(GADBannerView*)didFailToReceiveAdWithError`.
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AdMob will invoke `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` if there is no internet connection. Make sure you register the delegate to listen for callback methods:

`[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];`

You should also consider [AdMob Mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation) instead of trying to roll your own mediation solution. You can just create a mediation placement in the AdMob UI, add in the [iAd adapter](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation) to your project, and request an ad with the mediation placement ID, and the ad showing through different networks will be done for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was following a guide before, and they never put in `setDelegate:self`, hate that I didn't think of looking for that.. I didn't because everything else worked perfectly.. weird. Thanks!